# i'am trying to make web application in go, but stuck in connecting html file

Tags: go

Ok so following is my code:

```
import (
    "net/http"

    "html/template"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var templates *template.Template 
func main() {
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
    r := mux.NewRouter()                           
    r.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler).Methods("GET") 

    http.Handle("/", r) 
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
}
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)
}
```

and I'm getting this error: **panic: html/template: pattern matches no files: `index.html`**

this is sequence of my files:
[image]

can any of you can help?

edit: [image]

I hope this will help!

Comment: ok so i've Updated the question!

Comment: The panic is on main.go, line 13.  The ParseGlob pattern on line 13 is "template/*.html", but the error returned from ParseGlob complains about the pattern "index.html".   The file that you are running does not match the file shown in the image.

Comment: I did'nt get this, I mean can you please tell the solution

Comment: We do not have enough information to determine why the code displayed in the question is different from the code you are running.  Did you save the file before running it?  Are you running a main.go from a different directory than the main.go displayed in the question?

Comment: Your code works as is.  If you are using VS Code, did you save your changes to main.go?